# Function only after all asynchronous callbacks are completed in if statements

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

I want to close some page when all the callbacks from asynchronous functions are done, but not all `if()` statements might be true. Right now it looks like this:

```
if (this.originalFrom > addFrom) {
      this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
if (this.originalTo < addTo) {
      this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details2).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
if (this.originalTo > addTo) {
      this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details3).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    }
some_Page_Closing_Function_When_All_Callbacks_Are_Done();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) :

```
var promises = [];

if (this.originalFrom > addFrom) {
    promises.push(this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details));
}

if (this.originalTo < addTo) {
    promises.push(this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details2));
} else if (this.originalTo > addTo) {
    promises.push(this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details3));
}

Promise.all(promises).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Actually, I prefer this answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to call the function after all callbacks are done. If one if statement returns false then you want to seize the entire process.

One inferior way of doing this is by nesting the callbacks in this format:

```
  1 if (this.originalFrom > addFrom) {
  2     this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details).then((result) => {
  3         console.log(result);
  4         if (this.originalTo < addTo) {
  5             this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details2).then((result) => {
  6                 console.log(result);
  7                 if (this.originalTo > addTo) {
  8                     this.dataService.addTimeSlots(details3).then((result) => {
  9                         console.log(result);
 10                         some_Page_Closing_Function_When_All_Callbacks_Are_Done();
 11                     }, (err) => {
 12                         console.log(err);
 13                     });
 14                 }
 15             }, (err) => {
 16                 console.log(err);
 17             });
 18         }
 19
 20     }, (err) => {
 21         console.log(err);
 22     });
 23 }
```

However, this is known as callback hell. Verbose, unreadable, unmaintainable spagetti code.

You could try transforming the anonymouse functions into named functions for a more readable solution. This is still kind-of hacky.

https://github.com/caolan/async

https://caolan.github.io/async/

You can use this library to avoid the above callback hell.